# Ebean ORM seed data

Tags: ebean

If I have these settings in `ebean.properties`, the ORM sets up the tables when loading for the first time.

```
ebean.ddl.generate=true
ebean.ddl.run=true
```

I have this `create` file at classpath.

```
//h2-create.sql
create table user (
  id                        integer not null,
  username                  varchar(120) not null,
  password                  varchar(120) not null,
  constraint uq_user_password unique (password),
  constraint pk_user primary key (id))
;

create sequence user_seq;
```

However this does not seed initial data into the tables even if I add the `insert` statements to the `create` file.

What can I do if I also want data seeded at load time.

Answer (score 3):

In Ebean 6.15.1 you can specify a seed sql script to run via ebean.ddl.seedSql

For example:

```
ebean.ddl.generate=true
ebean.ddl.run=true
## only run the generated create-all dll and not the drop
ebean.ddl.createOnly=true

## Run test.seed.sql ... to populate some seed data prior to running the tests
ebean.ddl.seedsql=test.seed.sql
```

Refer to https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/515